# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Offline Installer (ISO)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After digging around for Visual Studio IDE 2015 update 3 offline installer, aka ISO file, I found it and I am sharing the url.

And, I know this may be posted elsewhere. But I also do know that many people try to find it on StackOverflow.

Comment: isn't possible for us to download the update 3 patch installer only?i mean....
not the whole VS2015, because we're already have the VS2015.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**
As per March 7, 2017, `Visual Studio 2017` [was released for general availability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/07/announcing-visual-studio-2017-general-availability-and-more/).

You can refer to **Mehdi Dehghani** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134857/visual-studio-2015-update-3-offline-installer-iso/40068343#40068343) for the direct download links
**or** the old-fashioned ways using the website, **vibs2006** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433282/6458107)

And you can also combine it with **Behrouz.M** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134857/visual-studio-2015-update-3-offline-installer-iso/39463050#39463050) to make it a complete full standalone offline installer.

---

> Note:
> **I don't condone any illegal use** of the offline installer.
> Please **stop piracy** and **follow the EULA**.

> The community edition is free even for commercial use, under some condition.
> You can see the EULA in this link below.
> https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547
> Thank you.

<s>Instruction for official offline installer:</s>

1. Open this link

> https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

2. **Scroll Down (DO NOT FORGET!)**
3. Click on **"Visual Studio 2015"** panel heading
4. Choose the edition that you want

> These menu should be available in that panel:
>
> - Community 2015
> - Enterprise 2015
> - Professional 2015
> - Enterprise 2015
> - Visual Studio 2015 Update
> - Visual Studio 2015 Language Pack
> - Visual Studio Test Professional 2015 Language Pack
> - Test Professional 2015
> - Express 2015 for Desktop
> - Express 2015 for Windows 10

5. Choose the language that you want in the drop-down menu (above the Download button)

> The language drop-down menu should be like this:
>
> - English *for English*
> - Deutsch *for German*
> - Español *for Spanish*
> - Français *for French*
> - Italiano *for Italian*
> - Русский *for Russian*
> - 日本語 *for Japanese*
> - 简体中文 *for Chinese (Simplified)*
> - 繁體中文 *for Chinese (Traditional)*
> - 한국어 *for Korean*

6. Check on **"ISO"** in radio-button menu (on the left side of the Download button)

> The radio-button menu should be like this:
>
> - Web installer
> - **ISO**

7. Click the **Download** button

Comment: Can not download English version of Community Edition. I choose English in drop-down menu, but German version is downloaded. :(

Comment: @Wildcat It seems Microsoft has updated the download page with redirect link to https://beta.visualstudio.com/downloads/, just a little different step though, I'll update it. I'm unable to reproduce your problem, what file name did you receive? Make sure it is **vs2015.3.com_enu.iso**

Comment: `beta` domain is no longer available. You can download installer (offline as well) by the next link: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Answer (score 90):

<del>You can check [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) for available `Visual Studio Community`, `Visual Studio Professional`, `Visual Studio Enterprise` and `Visual Studio Code` download links.</del>

---

**Update!**

There is no direct links of `Visual Studio 2015` at [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) anymore. **but the below links still works**.

---

**Visual Studio 2015** direct download links (**.iso**):

- [Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3 (*7.22 GB*)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/3/843ec655-1b67-46c3-a7a4-10a1159cfa84/vs2015.3.ent_enu.iso)
- [Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3 (*7.22 GB*)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/c/ebc2c43f-3821-4a0b-82b1-d05368af1604/vs2015.3.pro_enu.iso)
- [Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3 (*7.19 GB*)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/e/d/bedddfc4-55f4-4748-90a8-ffe38a40e89f/vs2015.3.com_enu.iso)

---

**VSCode area**:

- Windows

  - **`64 bit`**: [User Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-user) | [System Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64) | [.zip](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-archive)
  - `32 bit`: [User Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-user) | [System Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32) | [.zip](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-archive)
  - `ARM`: [User Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-arm64-user) | [System Installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-arm64) | [.zip](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-arm64-archive)
- Linux

  - `.deb`: [64-bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-x64) | [ARM](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-armhf) | [ARM 64](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-arm64)
  - `.rpm`: [64-bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-rpm-x64) | [ARM](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-rpm-armhf) | [ARM 64](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-rpm-arm64)
  - `.tar.gz` [64 bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-x64) | [ARM](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-armhf) | [ARM 64](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-arm64)
- Mac

  - `.zip`: [Universal](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=darwin-universal) | [Intel Chip](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=darwin) | [Apple Silicon](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=darwin-arm64)

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you tell me why?

Comment: This always save me a ton of time. thanks

Answer (score 18):

The ISO file that suggested in the accepted answer is still not complete. The very complete offline installer is about 24GB! There is only one way to get it. follow these steps:

1. Download Web Installer from Microsoft Web Site
2. Execute the Installer. NOTE: the installer is still a simple
   downloader for the real web-installer.
3. After running the real web installer, Run Windows Task manager and
   find the real web installer path that is stored in your `temp`
   folder
4. copy the real installer somewhere else. like `C:\VS Community\`
5. Open Command Prompt and execute the installer that you copied to `C:\VS
   Community\` with this argument: `/Layout .`
6. Now installer will download the FULL offline installer to your selected
   folder!

Good Luck

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, the ISO still tries to download things.

Comment: Thanx. I followed your answer. For the official steps: Creating an Offline Installation of Visual Studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

Comment: This *nearly* worked for me. Unfortunately, running the command with /Layout fails to complete with the log-file indicating download-propblemes for P8 and P9:
[09A4:2584][2022-02-07T11:58:23]i000: MUX:  P8 - The download for the /Layout operation failed with the following reason(s): Burn layout for 'VSU_14.0.25420' failed with exit code '1603'..
[09A4:2584][2022-02-07T11:58:23]i000: MUX:  P9 - The download for the /Layout operation failed with the following reason(s): Burn layout for 'VSU_14.0.25420' failed with exit code '1603'..

Answer (score 10):

So, you may download it from:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=708984

And I got this from:
http://blogs.bukutamudigital.com/2016/06/28/visual-studio-2015-update-3-offline-installer/

It's around 6GB

Comment: FWIW the same link was posted by a VS program manager at [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0 Available Now](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/#comment-180615). Long thread, with more tidbits about installation and Python issues.

Answer (score 7):

Its better to go through the **Recommended Microsoft's Way** to download **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 ISO (Community Edition)**.

The instructions below will help you to download any version of Visual Studio or even SQL Server etc provided by Microsoft in an easy to remember way. Though I recommend people using VS 2017 as there are not much big differences between 2015 and 2017.

Please follow the steps as mentioned below.

1. Visit the standard URL [www.visualstudio.com/downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)
2. Scroll down and click on encircled below as shown in snapshot down
   [image: Snapshot showing how to download older visual studio versions]
3. After that join Visual Studio Web Dev essentials for Free as shown below. Try loggin in with your microsoft account and see that if it works otherwise click on Join[image]
4. Click on Downloads ICON on the encircled as shown below. [image]
5. Now Type **Visual Studio Community** in the **Search Box** as shown below in the snapshot [image].
6. From the drowdown select the **DVD** type and start downloading [image]

Comment: This does not have the Express version of VS 2015.

Comment: @George Express Versions are replaced by **Community** versions if I'm correct. Express Version for SQL Server still comes but about Visual Studio 2013 on wards i don't think it comes anymore.

Comment: The Community version has different licensing criteria, compared to Express. It does not replace Express, because it does not serve the same purpose as Express did. Express offers a small subset of what Enterprise offers, but allows use in production environments. Community offers everything that Enterprise offers, except CodeLens, BUT the catch is that Community cannot be used for development, by companies with >250 machines or $1m in annual revenue. My company has various dummy machines for testing, and hence, does not qualify. Thus, I need Express. I'll be grateful if you can find it :)

Comment: @George will this link work for you if you want limited Visual Studio 2015 Express. However it is **_Online Web installer_** only. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691984&clcid=0x409
 I think that if you are looking for licensing issues then you can try **Visual Studio Code** which can be customized as per company's needs as everything in it is loosely coupled.

Comment: Thank you for trying @vibs2006 . :)  However, just like how the question points out, I'm interested in the ISO, so that it can be installed in multiple machines without wasting bandwidth downloading via the Web Installer. Also, Visual Studio Code is an Editor, whereas Visual Studio and it's Express variant are IDEs.

Comment: @George as you can see in this snapshot https://imgur.com/a/mT0By (just taken by me) that microsoft only hosts .exe for express officially