# How to get compiler version 19.0.24234 for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When researching on `libmdbx`, I found its sources require MSVC compiler version >= `19.0.24234` for "Visual Studio 2015 Update 3".

I have to stick to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, cannot upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 or later. But my compiler version is `19.00.24223`.

It seems that if you install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 freshly from an offline ISO, the initial compiler version would be `19.00.24215.1`. (ref: [Offline install ISO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134857/visual-studio-2015-update-3-offline-installer-iso))

Then if you install [this update (KB4020481)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81dbe6bb-ed92-411a-bef5-3a75ff972c6a/vc14-kb4020481.exe), the compiler version is bumped to `19.00.24223`

I installed [this update (KB3165756)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt752379(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), the compiler version did not change.

There is a page listing all `_MSC_VER_FULL` values:
https://dev.to/yumetodo/list-of-mscver-and-mscfullver-8nd

The version number for 2015 Update 3 is `190024210`.

So is `190024234` really a valid compiler version from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3? Or is it actually from Visual Studio 2017?

If you search google with "`_MSC_FULL_VER 190024234`", you will get very few results, with top ones being the github sources from user `erthink`, where happnes to be the repo of `libmdbx`. In the source it claims that `19.00.24234` corresponds to Visual Studio 2015. So is there any "KB" update that can bump the compiler versio to that required one? Thanks.

```cpp
#   if _MSC_FULL_VER < 190024234
        /* Actually libmdbx was not tested with compilers older than 19.00.24234 (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3).
         * But you could remove this #error and try to continue at your own risk.
         * In such case please don't rise up an issues related ONLY to old compilers.
         */
#       error "At least \"Microsoft C/C++ Compiler\" version 19.00.24234 (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3) is required."
#   endif
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/this-update-requires-visual-studio-2015-update-3-to-be-installed/

Comment: Your link's solution is to install `KB3165756`, as I have mentioned in the question, installing that KB does not change the compiler version.

Comment: _"So is 190024234 really a valid compiler version from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3?"_ It seems that at least one person was using this compiler version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718832/inconsistent-truncation-of-unsigned-bitfield-integer-expressions-between-c-and but it's not clear if it's Visual Studio 2015 or a newer version. [This site](https://dev.to/yumetodo/list-of-mscver-and-mscfullver-8nd) lists version 1900 as Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. The next newer Visual Studio 2017 has version 1910

Comment: is there a reason you can't upgrade to VS2017+? Because since VS2015 MS changed to [Universal CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=msvc-160) which has a stable ABI and is compatible with later MSVC versions so you can build with the latest MSVC version and it'll just work, no need to stick and build with a specific version

Comment: @jabaa So it seems that `19.00.24234` should be a VS2015 compiler version. VS2017 should have minor version set to 01. That's why I'm curious what update should I apply to VS2015 to get `19.00.24234`.


@phuclv Unfortunately the reason is not technical.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks for the hint, searching `19.00.24234.1` leads me to this page: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5a1a6d14-4076-4bcb-a8c6-d83c98c7f83e/c-standards-in-microsoft-visual-c-compilers?forum=vcgeneral  So this compiler version is the VS2015 toolset bundled in VS2017, probably it's not available in VS2015 Update 3. The author of `libmdbx` probably also uses the VS2015 toolset from VS2017, hence he sees the compiler version as `19.00.24234`.